# How to disable arrow key navigation on PrimeNG Table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Is there a way to disable arrow key (left, right, up & down) navigation in Primng Table [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo). ? Tab key should work.

Answer (score 1):

I disable the following methods definition in `\node_modules\primeng\fesm2015\primeng-table.js` and now arrow keys don't navigate the cursor:-

- onArrowUp(event)
- onArrowDown(event)
- onArrowLeft(event)
- onArrowRight(event)